# Reading sheet contents for Stored procedure body and creating in oracle

Tags: excel, vba, oracle, stored-procedures

My stored procedure contains 13000+ characters, I am trying to create this SP in oracle using excel VBA.

I placed full SP body in single cell in excel sheet then I read and stored in string

> sp_code = Worksheets("properties").Cells(2, 1).Value

Later using ADODB.Command I pushed code to oracle but it give error like below

```
identifier too long
```

I came across through web docs like vba won't handle more than 255 characters in a identifier, So I break the sp code and placed in each cell and declared a variant then push the code like below.

```
sp_code = Worksheets("properties").Range("B2:J2").Value
cmd_meta.CommandText = sp_code(1, 1) & sp_code(1, 2) & sp_code(1, 3) & sp_code(1, 4)
```

But still got same error.

Please share your thoughts and possible ways to get solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

@duplicate markers - please tag the link of duplicate before marking mine.

Comment: Not much to go on here.  Can we assume your command works when pasted into an Oracle command window in a query tool?  From the error message it sounds like there's some problem with the procedure code itself, but since we can't see it I'm not sure what we can offer there.  Are you able to successfully create a small, simple SP using the VBA approach?

Comment: Why do you try to create PL/SQL code with VBA? Consider the standard tools like sqlplus or an IDE like TOAD or SQL Developer.They should work much better.

Comment: The problem should be in your PL/SQL code. As it is rather big, created it in proper IDE which should tell you the line where the error occurs.

Comment: I am developing a tool. It need to check and create a SP if it doesn't exist across multiple environments wherever it is used. 
SP code I am using is fine and it is executing well in Oracle. (It has 130+ lines)..
I am looking for a possibility to refer the body of SP from excel sheet thru VBA and create it in oracle.

Comment: @Tim Williams - Yes I am able to create a SP from VBA in Oracle with few lines as SP body